# Unable to call external servlet from Flex app

Tags: apache-flex, servlets, securityexception

I am callng a servlet from a browser based Flex app but get the following exception:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2170: Security sandbox violation: http://MyURL/web-player/WebPlayer.swf cannot send HTTP headers to http:/MyOtherUrl:1936/ImageUpload.
      at WebPlayer/screenGrab()
      at WebPlayer/__exportImageButton_click()
```

I have the following crossdomain.xml being served from

```
http://MyOtherUrl/
```

and

```
http://MyOtherUrl:1936/
```

(the port the servlet is served from).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
  <cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" />
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain='*' headers="*" secure="false"/>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit to include code

---

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
urlRequest.url = "http://MyUrl:1936/ImageUpload";
urlRequest.contentType = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + UploadPostHelper.getBoundary();
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
var params:Object = new Object();
params.userId = userId;
params.videoId = videoId;
urlRequest.data = UploadPostHelper.getPostData("splash.jpg", jpegStream, params);
urlRequest.requestHeaders.push( new URLRequestHeader( 'multipart/form-data', 'image/jpg' ) );

var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

Comment: How do you "Call a Servlet" in a Flex app?  I'm not familiar with that terminology; so I'm unclear exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm building a UrlRequest passing the various data items I require and adding the header then call load on the request. I know that the servlet call works as I can both call both a local version and the deployed version, but only when I'm running my Flex app in the sandbox.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the pertinent code, as I say though I can execute this code successfully when running in the security sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

try checking whether your crossdomain.xml is accessible from browser.
Go to MyOtherUrl:1936/crossdomain.xml

Check the traffic with http://www.charlesproxy.com/
to see what is the error.

Comment: This is not an answer; but merely troubleshooting suggestions.  It is usually considered best practice to add these as a comment on the main question; not as a formal answer.

Comment: Yes the crossdomain.xml is accessible from a browser.